# In this specific example, can I have more than one fact table?

Tags: schema, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, fact-table

I have the following assignment for Business Intelligence Class:

- "The CSUF Business Association is conducting a babysitter service as a fundraiser
  for different clubs in college. When a customer is entered into the system, the
  CSUF Club coordinator gets name, address, and phone. The coordinator also
  records each babysitting job, the amount paid for it and the sitter assigned to
  the job. Each person may sign up to credit only one club and the system keeps
  the contact person and phone number for each participating club.
- The treasurer wants a data warehouse for this. He would like to be able to
  determine how much each customer was billed by week, month, or year. How
  much each employee (sitter) earned, also summed by time periods. He is
  interested in how much work is done on weekends, holidays or other special
  days.
- Develop a data warehouse using the methodology you prefer to provide this
  information (including fact and dimension tables, their attributes, keys, and
  relationships), referring the name of the schema that was adopted."

I was thinking about the following fact tables:

| Fact_CustBill |
| --- |
| Dim_Time_ID |
| Dim_Club_ID |
| Dim_Cust_ID |
| Fact_BilledAmount |

| Fact_EmployeeEarns |
| --- |
| Dim_Time_ID |
| Dim_Club_ID |
| Dim_Emp_ID |
| Fact_EarnedAmount |

| Fact_WorkSpecial |
| --- |
| Dim_TimeSpecial_ID |
| Fact_HoursWorked |

I'm thinking about these fact tables just based on an example I was given during class. I'm not sure about Dim_Club_ID being necessary on the employee tables and I'm also not 100% about the "Fact_WorkSpecial". Is my reasoning correct or not really?

Comment: A fact is basically an event. You need to think about how many events are included in the description - and be clear what are actually standalone events (which go into a fact table) and what are aggregated views of those standalone events (which query against existing fact tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple fact tables. And you should have multiple fact tables if you’re recording data of different granularity.

But in this case one fact table is enough for both employee revenues and amounts biller to customers. The grain is the same: the babysitting job.

So you can have one fact table linking to club, date, customer and employee dimensions, with multiple measures: hours worked, amount billed to client and amount earned by employee.

When you want to report you can pick only one of those measures and query on it. But it will give you more info: whether some clients prefer to work with certain employees.

The trick here is your date dimension. It needs calendar year, month and day, but also year of week (iso 8601), week number and day of the week.